# What is Record in CRM?

Tags: database-design, dynamics-crm, crm, sugarcrm

My question is simple. What is the meaning of record in CRM database? and how is this reflected on CRM database design?
For example:
Is there is a relation between contact and account and record?
Is there is a relation between sale transaction or phone call and record?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An instance of a contact is a record.

An instance of an account is a record.

A record can be seen as a row in a table - or a row in a view in CRM (e.g. the My Contacts view).
A table in CRM is known as an Entity, e.g. contact entity, account entity, etc.

Therefore a record is an instance of an Entity.

There is no relation between a contact and an account record - if you are talking in relational database terms. You can make a relationship between them, if you wish. In CRM, you can create one-to-many, many-to-one and many-to-many relationships though customization.